# Removing rows from a table based off values in another conditional on a value in a separate column using base R

Tags: r, datatable, subset

I have a table :

```
ID Phenotype 
AA 1
AB 1
AC 0
AD 1
AE 0
AF 1
AG 0
```

I have a list of IDs of those with the "1" phenotype that I want to subset from the other "1" phenotypes. I want to keep all the "0" phenotypes.

Say the list read: AB, AD

The desired outcome would be:

```
        ID Phenotype 
        AA 1
        AB 1
        AC 0
        AD 1
        AE 0
        AG 0
```

I.E. AF would have been removed as it was a phenotype "1" but was not on the list and all the phenotype "0" have remained untouched.

In reality table and the list are thousands of entries long. All the IDs are unique.

I work on a HPC which is airlocked to outside tools so base R solutions are preferred. I can subset the table into phenotypes 1 and 0, remove those I do not want and then rejoin the table but I was wondering if there was a one-liner way of doing this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Base `R` one-liner would be:

**Code:**

```
df[df[, 1] %in% v | df[, 2] == 0, ]

# checks which data.frame entries are matched in the supplied vector

df[, 1] %in% v 

# checks which second column entries equal 0

df[, 2] == 0

# then we just utilize | to tell R to accept entries that satisfy either of our 
# conditions
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID Phenotype 
AA 1
AB 1
AC 0
AD 1
AE 0
AF 1
AG 0", header = T)

v <- c("AB", "AD")
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Worked well. Just for my learning the code says: search df in column 1 those values that exist in v. The "|" symbol means pipe like in linux? Pipe these results into those rows where the second column is 0?

Comment: @tacrolimus  I added a few comments hope that clears things up

Comment: Brilliant - again thanks for taking the time to answer and explain. It really helps novices get to grips with things! All the best